# How to overcome the Wrong merging When using Pivot_Table?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, multiple-columns

I have Two Dataframes ,What I'm trying to to do , is to create new columns based on the Sensor_Type and add them to DF1 and assign each measurement based on the Sensor.

DF1:

```
  Weather_Legends.head():

  Sensor_ID Sensor_Street_Name  Sensor_Lat  Sensor_Long   Sensor_Type         UOM
 0  6030    Milano - via Brera  45.471192   9.187616    Wind Direction      degree
 1  5897    Milano - via Brera  45.471192   9.187616      Temperature   Celsius degree
 2  6174    Milano - via Brera  45.471192   9.187616    Relative Humidity      %
 3  6120    Milano - via Brera  45.471192   9.187616      Wind Speed         m/s
 4  2006    Milano - via Lambrate  45.490051  9.22559   Precipitation        mm
```

DF2:

```
  Mi_Meteo.head():

  Sensor_ID    Time_Instant     Measurement
0   14121   2013-11-01 01:00:00   0.8
1   14121   2013-11-01 02:00:00   0.6
2   14121   2013-11-01 03:00:00   0.4
3   14121   2013-11-01 04:00:00   0.4
4   14121   2013-11-01 05:00:00    0
```

And this is the desired output:

```
Sensor_Type Sensor_ID   Sensor_Street_Name             Time_Instant      Precipitation     Relative Humidity    Wind Speed  …..
     0      14121     Milano - via Ippolito Rosellini   2013-11-01 01:00:00   0.8              NaN              NaN
     1      14121     Milano - via Ippolito Rosellin    2013-11-01 02:00:00   NaN              0.6              NaN
     2      14121     Milano - via Ippolito Rosellini   2013-11-01 03:00:00   0.4               NaN             NaN
     .
     .
     .
```

And Instead , These Is What I get:

```
 Sensor_Type Sensor_ID  Sensor_Street_Name               Time_Instant     Precipitation
   0          14121    Milano - via Ippolito Rosellini   2013-11-01 01:00:00    0.8
   1          14121    Milano - via Ippolito Rosellini   2013-11-01 02:00:00    0.6
   2          14121    Milano - via Ippolito Rosellini   2013-11-01 03:00:00    0.4
   .
   .
```

The Other Sensor Type are Missing !!!

And Here's The Code That I Used:

```
    Mi_Meteo['Measurement'] = Mi_Meteo['Measurement'].str.rstrip(' Measure').str.strip()
    Mi_Meteo['Measurement'] = pd.to_numeric(Mi_Meteo['Measurement'] ,errors='coerce' )
    Mi_Meteo['Sensor_ID'] = Mi_Meteo['Sensor_ID'].str.rstrip(' ID').str.strip()
    Mi_Meteo['Sensor_ID'] = pd.to_numeric(Mi_Meteo['Sensor_ID'] ,errors='coerce' )

    Mi_Meteo['Measurement'] = Mi_Meteo['Measurement'].astype(float)
    Mi_Meteo['Sensor_ID'] = Mi_Meteo['Sensor_ID'].astype(float)

    df4 = Mi_Meteo.merge(Weather_Legends, on='Sensor_ID', how='left')\
                  .pivot_table(index=['Sensor_ID' ,'Sensor_Street_Name' , 'Time_Instant' ], 
                               values= 'Measurement', 
                               columns='Sensor_Type')\
                  .reset_index()
    df4['Sensor_ID'] = df4['Sensor_ID'].astype(int)
```

Any Suggestion Would Be Much Appreciated , Thank U all.

Comment: Try using an outer join if you want to preserve both keys?

Comment: I've Already Tried With 'outer' it's the same

Comment: Are you familiar with SQL, and with primary and foreign keys? From the first 2 tables, it seems that each sensor_id takes only one type of measurement. However, your 3rd table (desired output) shows that each sensor_id takes, in fact, multiple types of measurement. Which is it? There seems to be quite a big inconsistency in what you have shown us

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous , Unfortunately , I have no experience in SQL ,  but basically what i want it to do , is whenever it encounters a Senor_ID it assigns to it the appropriate Sensor_Type , for Exemple , everytime it sees the Sensor 14121 , it assigns to it the Ammonia Sensor Type and filling the other Sensor Type columns with Nan's.

Comment: You have not answered my question. What are the primary keys of the tables, ie what field are unique, with no repetition, in each table? Look up primary and foreign keys. It helps you understand how data should be structured. Is each sensor id associated to only one sensor type, or to more than one? Can you upload some of your data for us to have a look or is it confidential? PS so, how polluted is Milan? :)

Comment: oh , sure , each Sensor_ID is associated to only one Sensor Type , as to the Data I would gladly Upload it , but i don't know how (sorry about that)!!

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of your data, I made it up with some random data which mirrors what I understand is the structure of yours.

The code below works and gives you what I believe you're looking for. It is similar to what you seem to have done, so I can only guess there must be some errors in the structure of your data.

This is going to sound really banal, but have you verified that there are readings for the other sensors, too (wind etc)? Based on the output, it seems there are readings only for precipitation.

**Your 'desired output' doesn't make sense because it shows that the same sensor id records rain and humidity; but you said each sensor id is associated to only one sensor type!**

E.g. maybe 'sensor id' is not a primary key after the formulae you have applied? Look up these concepts here: https://www.essentialsql.com/what-is-the-difference-between-a-primary-key-and-a-foreign-key/ or in one of the trillion resources available online. Check the structure of your data.

Don't mean to sound like a broken record, but, again: **primary and foreign keys! You really really really really need to understand the structure of your data.**

If, after going over these concepts and after reviewing your data, you still can't see what's wrong with it, you might try uploading the data to dropbox or something similar, posting a link here and hoping some of us have enough time to go over it.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random

num_sensors=int(100)
sensors= pd.DataFrame()
sensors['sensor id']=np.arange(0,num_sensors)
sensors['address id'] =np.arange(1000,1000+num_sensors)
#;ambda function not efficient on large datasets but irrelevant here
sensors['type']= sensors.apply( lambda x: "".join( [random.choice(['rain','temp','wind']) ] ), axis=1 )

num_measurements = 10
meas = pd.DataFrame()
meas['sensor id']= np.repeat(sensors['sensor id'], num_measurements )
meas['time'] = np.tile( np.arange(0,num_measurements ), num_sensors )
meas['value'] =np.random.rand(num_measurements * num_sensors )
#otherwise the index is copied from the other dataframe, so is not unique
meas=meas.reset_index(drop=True)

joined = pd.merge(sensors, meas, how='outer', on='sensor id')
pt = joined.pivot_table( index= ['sensor id','address id','time'], columns=['type'], values=['value']  ).reset_index()
```

Comment: PS With this you can check how many readings per type per sensor you have; eg this tells you that sensor id one has 10 rain readings but 0 humidity readings, etc. Note I have constructed the data so that each sensor measures only one thing, but your 'desired output' shows otherwise:
``joined.pivot_table( index = 'sensor id', columns='type', values='value', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)

Comment: Thank's For all the Help Much Appreciated.

Comment: No worries. Post back here if you get it to work and find what the error was. My guess is there was something in the structure of your data you hadn't fully understood.

Comment: It Might be for sure , the thing is , i made it work perfectly yesterday , and today nothing ……., anyway thanks again for everything .

Comment: The philosophy of stack overflow is that you shouldn't post all your code and data, but just a minimalist example to help others understand and replicate your issue. This is also a great exercise that helps you debug. If the code works with the data structured the way I have, then it means the structure of your data is different. There are many issues I resolved, without even posting here, because I realised what the error was exactly while building a minimalist example for stackoverflow.